# Flutter Custompainter canvas drawimage not working

Tags: android, canvas, flutter, dart

I tried to draw image using Canvas and CustomPainter but it's not working. This is for an Android app using Flutter Framework.

I just used command `flutter build apk` in Windows cmd to build the app.

```dart
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Title!')),
      body: Center(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 1.0,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: ImageEditor(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageEditor extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  Future paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {
    canvas.save();

    ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load("assets/sampleImagees.jpg");

    final Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.view(bd.buffer);

    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);

    final ui.Image image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;

    canvas.drawImage(image, Offset(0.0, 0.0), Paint());

    canvas.save();
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

There isn't any error but nothing happend in the app. It's just a white screen.
What's wrong in my code?

[White screen of the builded app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGzoE.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your image needs to be available before the canvas is drawn. By moving the loading code outside of the painter, the painter now works as intended :

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  ui.Image _image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadImage();
  }

  _loadImage() async {
    ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load("assets/sampleImagees.jpg");

    final Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.view(bd.buffer);

    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);

    final ui.Image image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;

    setState(() => _image = image);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Title!')),
      body: Center(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 1.0,
          child: CustomPaint(
                painter: ImageEditor(_image),
              )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageEditor extends CustomPainter {
  ui.Image image;

  ImageEditor(this.image) : super();

  @override
  Future paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {
    if (image != null) {
      canvas.drawImage(image, Offset(0.0, 0.0), Paint());
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return image != (oldDelegate as ImageEditor).image;
  }
}
```

Note that you can easily draw an image using `Image.asset` instead of a `CustomPainter` :

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Title!')),
      body: Center(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 1.0,
          child: Image.asset('assets/sampleImagees.jpg'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Awsome! i tried this and worked for me but i am facing one issue is that image is not drawn to exact offset position any idea?

Comment: Could be difficult to help you without anymore information on your code. I would suggest you to create a new post with full details of your code. You would then also gain in visibility.

Comment: Thank you for your response but now i solved it!

Answer (score 2):

As [@Muldec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10574137/muldec) said, the image needs to be available before drawing it on the canvas. In that case the [FuturBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) is appropriate.

```dart
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  late Future<ui.Image> _image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _image = _loadImage('path/image.jpg');
  }

  Future<ui.Image> _loadImage(String imagePath) async {
    ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load(imagePath);
    final Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.view(bd.buffer);
    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
    final ui.Image image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;

    return image;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<ui.Image>(
        future: _image,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ui.Image> snapshot) {
          Widget centerChild;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            centerChild =
                CustomPaint(painter: ImageEditor(image: snapshot.data!));
          } else {
            centerChild = const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Title!')),
              body: Center(child: centerChild));
        });
  }
}

class ImageEditor extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image image;

  ImageEditor({required this.image});

  @override
  Future paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {
    canvas.save();

    canvas.drawImage(image, Offset(0.0, 0.0), Paint());

    canvas.save();
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```